# C# Getting a dataset column name based upon a bound textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am validating data in a textbox if nothing is entered

```
public bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        if (textBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " is a required field.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, I want to pass in the name argument as the actual name from the dataset datacolumn that the textbox is bound to.

```
public bool isValidData(List<TextBox> textBoxList)
    {
        foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxList)
        {
            //string name = techSupportDataSet.Technicians.NameColumn.ColumnName;
            IsPresent(textBox, name);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You can see that the commented out code explicitly gets a specific datacolumn name, but I want it to be a variable depending on the bound textbox.

I've tried looking up the MSDN docs but I can't seem to find any methods that would accept a bound control as a parameter. Any points in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: `TextBox` contains an array of `DataBindings` you could iterate over to find the one that's bound to the `Text` property, however the beauty of data binding is that it separates your view controls from the datasource by updating the datasource automatically.  All you should have to do is check if the column on the current record != ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying a field name in message box is not a good idea. for example if DBA has created a field `FName` for User's First Name then the message will be displayed like `FName  is a required field.` This will confuse the operator. You can assign the Display Name in that control's `AccessibleName` or `AccessibleDescription` property and then you can use it in your code.

```
//Assign display name in AccessibleName property
textBox.AccessibleName= "User's First Name"

//use that field
IsPresent(textBox, textBox.AccessibleName);
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason you mentioned was precisely why I was going for the dataset column name since the textbox name property would yield that sort of confusion. As you said though, the dataset column could be named similarly. I had glanced at AccessibleName but I wasn't sure it should be used for such a purpose. Cheers!

Comment: Basically `AccessibleName` and `AccessibleDescription` property are being used to describe the role of that control in their container panel or window. Suppose if you have placed an control on windows form and you have not set the text property of that control then how do you know that what is the role of that control and what is the purpose of that control. you can read about that property on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.accessiblename(v=vs.110).aspx) also.